# How to change the density range in DensityPlot?

Tags: plotting

This is an example from Mathematic Help,

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3},  
  ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

We can notice that the density values are from -1.0 to 1.0. However, I want to change  this automatic  density range to other values, for example, 0 to 0.5.  Of course, the density plot  should  be different.

This should be simple, however, I have no idea about it. Can you tell me how to change it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotRange.html) accepts up to three ranges of values for plots that have a third dimension. So, you would do this

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3},  
  ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {0, 0.5}}
]
```

where the first two instances of `Automatic` are for the x and y coordinates.

Comment: Thanks! I just need this command---PlotRange.

Comment: @Orders don't forget to mark the best answer as [accepted](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask). I normally wait a day before doing so, though, just in case superior answers come in.

Comment: Oddly enough, this isn't working for me. It's the first thing I've tried, but while the range of my data is about `{500,1700}`, setting `PlotRange->{Automatic,Automatic,{0,4000}}` doesn't change anything about the result.

The solution [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154269/plotrange-in-densityplot?rq=1) worked for me, though.

Answer (score 3):

You could try `Rescale`:

```
DensityPlot[
 Rescale[Sin[x] Sin[y], {-1, 1}, {0.25, 0.5}],
 {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3},
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: rescale]