# PlotRange in DensityPlot

Tags: plotting

I'd need to compare two different DensityPlot by keeping the PlotRange fixed: however I'm not able to do that because DensityPlot automatically fix the range of the plot to the {min,max} of the function.
I've been reading something about it, a tried some possible solutions (for example ColorFunctionScaling -> False) but non of them solved my problem.

Here is part of the code I'm using:

```
DensityPlot[(
 E^(-x^2 - y^2) (-1 - 4 x y))/Sqrt[\[Pi]], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-0.69, 0.69}},
 PlotPoints -> 150,
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{RGBColor[0.02, 1, 1], RGBColor[0, 0.48, 1], 
      RGBColor[0, 0, 0.73], Black, RGBColor[0.6, 0.22, 0], RGBColor[
      1, 0.55, 0], White}, #1] &),
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 250], Right],
 ImageSize -> 300,
 Background -> Transparent
 ]
DensityPlot[(
 E^(-x^2 - y^2) (2 x - 2 y))/Sqrt[\[Pi]], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-0.69, 0.69}},
 PlotPoints -> 150,
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{RGBColor[0.02, 1, 1], RGBColor[0, 0.48, 1], 
      RGBColor[0, 0, 0.73], Black, RGBColor[0.6, 0.22, 0], RGBColor[
      1, 0.55, 0], White}, #1] &),
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 250], Right],
 ImageSize -> 300,
 Background -> Transparent
 ]
```

and the output is the following:

[image]

[image]

where obviously the range of the plots is not -0.69:0.69 in both of them. Using the correct color scaling the orange/brown background in the first picture would be black as in the second one.

Any solution for fixing it?
Edit: I think the solution lies in using ColorData function in some way:
I noticed that, with a standard color function (e.g. "Heat") I can use the combination:

```
ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Heat", {-0.69, 0.69}}],
```

but I'm not able to reproduce it with my custom ColorFunction...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To compare the two plots you can rescale the first plot (f1) to the range of the second one:

```
f1 = (E^(-x^2 - y^2) (-1 - 4 x y)) / Sqrt[Pi];
f2 = (E^(-x^2 - y^2) (2 x - 2 y)) / Sqrt[Pi];

zr = Through[{NMinValue, NMaxValue}[{f2, -4 <= x <= 4}, {x, y}]]
```

> {-0.684397, 0.684397}

```
col = 
   {RGBColor[0.02, 1, 1], RGBColor[0, 0.48, 1], RGBColor[0, 0, 0.73], Black, 
    RGBColor[0.6, 0.22, 0], RGBColor[1, 0.55, 0], White};

Grid[{{
   DensityPlot[f1, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
    PlotRange -> zr,
    ColorFunction -> (Blend[col, Rescale[#, zr]] &),
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    ImageSize -> 300],

   DensityPlot[f2, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
    PlotRange -> zr,
    ColorFunction -> (Blend[col, #] &),
    ImageSize -> 300,
    PlotLegends -> Automatic]
   }}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

This problem can be solved by using ListDensityPlot and Blend.

First you have to obtain the discrete values of your functions:

```
f1 = Table[(E^(-x^2 - y^2) (-1 - 4 x y))/Sqrt[Pi], {x, -4, 4, 
0.2}, {y, -4, 4, 0.2}];
f2 = Table[(E^(-x^2 - y^2) (2 x - 2 y))/Sqrt[Pi], {x, -4, 4, 
0.2}, {y, -4, 4, 0.2}];
```

Second, using *Blend* function to map a given color range to your defined color scheme:

```
ColorFunction -> (Blend[
Transpose@{Subdivide[-0.684397, 0.684397, 6], 
  colormap}, #1] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False
```

notice that Subdivide[-0.684397, 0.684397, 6] is a list of the same length of your color scheme, and -0.684397, 0.684397 are the lowest and highest limits of the wanted color range (your fixed PlotRange).

So now this problem is settled already. The full codes and results are listed below

```
    f1 = Table[(E^(-x^2 - y^2) (-1 - 4 x y))/Sqrt[Pi], {x, -4, 4, 
    0.2}, {y, -4, 4, 0.2}];
    f2 = Table[(E^(-x^2 - y^2) (2 x - 2 y))/Sqrt[Pi], {x, -4, 4, 
    0.2}, {y, -4, 4, 0.2}];
    colormap = {RGBColor[0.02, 1, 1], RGBColor[0, 0.48, 1], 
    RGBColor[0, 0, 0.73], Black, RGBColor[0.6, 0.22, 0], RGBColor[1, 0.55, 0], White};
    options = {ColorFunction -> (Blend[
       Transpose@{Subdivide[-0.684397, 0.684397, 6], 
         colormap}, #1] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 3, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 200};
p1 = ListDensityPlot[f1, options];
p2 = ListDensityPlot[f2, options, PlotLegends -> Automatic];
Grid[{{p1, p2}}]
```

[image]